# Perl - Import contents of file into another file

Tags: perl, scripting, import

**The below code I'm trying to produce is trying to do this:**

> > What I'm trying to do is running a BTEQ script that gets data from a DB then exports to a flat-file, that flat file is picked up my a Perl script (the above code), then with this post trying to get perl to import that file it gets into a fastload file. Does that make more sense?

```
while (true) {
    #Objective: open dir, get flat-file which was exported from bteq
    opendir (DIR, "C:/q2refresh/") or die "Cannot open /my/dir: $!\n"; #open directory with the flat-file
    my @Dircontent = readdir DIR;
    $filetobecopied = "C:/q2refresh/q2_refresh_prod_export.txt";  #flatfile exported from bteq
    $newfile = "C:/q2refresh/Q2_FastLoadFromFlatFile.txt"; #new file flat-file contents will be copied to as "fastload"
    copy($filetobecopied, $newfile) or die "File cannot be copied.";
    close DIR;
    my $items_in_dir = @Dircontent;
        if ($items_in_dir > 2) {  # > 2 because of "." and ".."
-->>>>>>      # take the copied FlatFile above and import into a fastload script  located at C:/q2refresh/q2Fastload.txt
        }
        else {sleep 100;}
}
```

I need help with implementing the above bolded section. How do I import the contents of `C:/q2refresh/Q2_FastLoadFromFlatFile.txt` into a fastload script located at `C:/q2refresh/q2Fastload.txt`.

// I apologize if this is somewhat newbish, but I am new to Perl.

Thanks.

Comment: What "bolded section"? The bold formatting is overwritten by the code sample formatting.

Comment: See section above with -->>>>>> before it.

Comment: I think you need to clarify exactly what it is you are trying to do. This code really does not explain anything. It looks like you want to create a never-ending loop, which constantly copies a file into place, overwriting itself every loop.

Comment: Please see bolded title above of what im trying to do.\

Comment: I know perl, but I don't know what a fastload file is, and what you mean by "import into".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($items_in_dir > 2) {  # > 2 because of "." and ".."
```

Well, when including `.` and `..`, plus the two copies of `q2_refresh_prod_export.txt`, you will always have more than 2 files in the directory. If such a case should occur that `q2_refresh_prod_export.txt` is not copied, the script will `die`. *So the `else` clause will never be called.*

Also, it is pointless to copy the file to a new place, if you are simply going to copy it to another place in a second. It's not like "cut & paste", you actually, physically copy the file to a new file, not a clipboard.

If by "import into" mean that you want to append the contents of `q2_refresh_prod_export.txt` to an existing `q2Fastload.txt`, there are ways to do that, such as what Troy suggested in another answer, with an `open` and `>>` (append to).

You will have to sort out what you mean by this whole `$items_in_dir` condition. You are keeping files and copying files in that directory, so what is it exactly that you are checking for? Whether the files have all been removed (by some other process)?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what you're trying to do. Could it be that you just want to do this?

```
open SOURCE, $newfile;
open SINK, '>>C:/q2refresh/q2Fastload.txt';
while (<SOURCE>) {
    print SINK $_;
}
close SOURCE;
close SINK;
```

That will append the contents of $newfile to your fastload file.

Comment: Troy- What I'm trying to do is running a BTEQ script that gets data from a DB then exports to a flat-file, that flat file is picked up my a Perl script (the above code), then with this post trying to get perl to import that file it gets into a fastload file. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I think your problem is that nobody so far is familiar with FastLoad or its file format.

Comment: @Troy That would be my main problem.